# How do I apply an irregular shape to the top borders of a repeating linear gradient?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to replicate the below pattern in CSS, but I'm having trouble styling the last bit, which is the irregular shape (an extra "block" jutting out of the top of each little black square)

I can't find a way to manipulate the small repeated boxes to do that, so that they match the picture:

[image: reference photo with ideal pattern]

This is my code so far:

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: conic-gradient(transparent 0deg, transparent 150deg, black 90deg, black 270deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, white 0px, transparent 0px, transparent 50%, white 50%, white), 
                    repeating-linear-gradient( 90deg, white 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 50%, white 50%, white), 
                    repeating-linear-gradient( 180deg, white 0px, transparent 0px, transparent 50%, white 50%, white), 
                    repeating-linear-gradient( 180deg, white 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 50%, white 50%, white), 
                    repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black 0px, transparent 0px, transparent 40%, black 40%, black), 
                    repeating-linear-gradient( 225deg, black 0px, transparent 0px, transparent 50%, black 50%, black);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The goal here is to improve my abilities with CSS, so non-CSS solutions are not useful here.

Comment: If you are content with each little blob being a square then draw them as diamonds and rotate the element by 45 degrees.

Comment: The small shape is not clear, can you give us a better visual?